# Get a thread by Id

Tags: java, jmx

I worked in JMX java and I get all the thread IDs by using the `getAllThreadIds ()` method of the interface `ThreadMXBean` but I need a way to kill the thread of a given ID.

for example:

```
ThreadMXBean tbean;
tbean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
long[] IDs=tbean.getAllThreadIds();
//.... I need a way to kill the Threads which have this IDs
```

Answer (score 11):

You can try this:

```
public void printAllThreadIds() {
    Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = getRootThreadGroup(currentThread);
    int allActiveThreads = threadGroup.activeCount();
    Thread[] allThreads = new Thread[allActiveThreads];
    threadGroup.enumerate(allThreads);

    for (int i = 0; i < allThreads.length; i++) {
        Thread thread = allThreads[i];
        long id = thread.getId();
        System.out.println(id);
    }
}

private static ThreadGroup getRootThreadGroup(Thread thread) {
    ThreadGroup currentGroup = thread.getThreadGroup();

    ThreadGroup parentGroup;
    while ((parentGroup = currentGroup.getParent()) != null) {
        currentGroup = parentGroup;
    }

    return currentGroup;
}
```

**But you should interrupt a `Thread` and not `stop` it.**

The `Thread.stop()` method is deprecated, because it immediately kills a `Thread`. Thus data structures that are currently changed by this `Thread` might remain in a inconsistent state. The interrupt gives the Thread the chance to shutdown gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually no good way to kill a thread in java. There used be an api called Thread.stop() but it is also deperecated. Check this link for more details why Thread.stop was bad and how we should be stopping a thread.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Getting just the thread id will not help you, you need to have the thread object reference to set a flag to stop that thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method:

```
static Map<Thread,StackTraceElement[]>  getAllStackTraces()
```

to get all threads, then traverse map by key and find appropriate thread.

But this is a very bad approach. How are you going to stop thread? Using `void stop()` method? Id suggest using Executor framework in conjunction with interruption mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.getAllStackTraces` returns all stack traces of all live threads `Map<Thread,StackTraceElement[]>.` These are supposed to be the same threads that ThreadMXBean returns. You can extract threads from this map and interrupt them. Note that there is no legal method in Java to kill a thread.