# Terminating thread using thread Id in java

Tags: java

I want to terminate thread using it's Id.

using below statement  I'm getting thread. this thread Id I'm maintaining in `Hashtable`.

```
long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
```

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Get the thread as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224253/get-a-thread-by-id/18224488#18224488

and interrupt it.

Comment: just keep the references of your custom threads instead of ID and use `Thread.interrupt()`  to terminate the thread or maintain a `Map<String,Thread>` for each thread id.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
//Give you set of Threads
Set<Thread> setOfThread = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();

//Iterate over set to find yours
for(Thread thread : setOfThread){
    if(thread.getId()==yourThread.getId()){
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first real answer to the question, upvote! By the way, there's no need to cast `Set` to array in this case, you may just iterate on `setOfThread`

Comment: Java 8: `setOfThread.stream().findAny(t->t.getId()==id).ifPresent(Thread::interrupt);`

Answer (score 0):

I would say a good way to do this is to create an implementation of java.lang.Runnable which has a stop() method. Like so:

```
public class Stoppable implements Runnable
```

{
    private boolean stopRequested = false;

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    // Thread code
    if (stopRequested)
    {
        // Perform any tidy up activities and return from the run method

        return;
    }
}

public void stop()
{
    stopRequested = true;
}
```

}

You could instead use the java built in interrupt approach also. thread.interrupt(). Then in your runnable you would do a check on that. Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() However I've always preferred to use a separate variable and code, just gives me more control.

If you're on Java 7 onwards then try the executors http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html
They provide a lot of useful features like return types and exception handling which has always been a little annoying with the traditional threads approach.

Comment: Wouldn't synchronization be a more logic specific requirement? I mean, you don't really need to use synchronization right since each runnable is a separate instance on it's own thread.
What did you have in mind for synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224253/get-a-thread-by-id) to get a thread by it's id and then interrupt it, however, as mentioned in comments, you should not do this. Use Thread-Object-References instead and handle the Threads directly.