# How To Shut Down Specific Task(Process) of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor In Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Hello everyone**

I want to terminate or shut-down a specific task in ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

e.g.
i want to set a unique id or name for each task i will queue then shut it down using its id or name which i added to this task

> that is because i have users and my application use case force me to specify tasks for each user but sometimes i want to shut down specific task for specific user

*for example*

```
user.setTaskId('john-deo-1521');
user.setTaskId('john-deo-1522');
```

and  for shutting down

```
taskExecutor.shutDownTaskById('john-deo-1521');
```

and this is my main configuration for ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ServiceExecutorConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(30);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(40);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;

    }
}
```

Comment: May be this link can help you : [Terminate thread by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213615/terminating-thread-using-thread-id-in-java)